# Acronyms: best-practice?

Tags: discussion

I have found several times in a question that the user assumes as known some acronyms ([LLC](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/46420/19366), [HIPAA](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/46608/19366), ...).

Should these acronyms be edited with a link or a clarification about what do they mean?

Some of these might be world-wide known, like company positions (CEO, CTO...) or not, others might be local. Should we do something with acronyms? Which is the guide-lines when we found an acronym not described previously on the question?

Comment: FWIW IDK, BTW! :)

Comment: When I do this, I usually leave a comment for the OP to remind him that he is adressing an international audience. Occasionally, if the question shows little effort (bad quality) I will not do the edit myself, but leave a note with an edit link, asking the OP to improve the question himself. Teach a man to fish...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can always edit questions/answers to clarify or add links. This is great that you are thinking about this!

Once you have enough reputation (2000) those edits will be automatically approved. Until that point they go into the suggested edit review queue, where anyone with over 2000 reputation can approve them.

Comment: What about the second part of the question? We should always edit, or just to some extend

Comment: @Llopis I guess just use your judgement on that. I don't think there is a defined "rule" for that, I've been thinking about how to answer your question here and am not sure!

Comment: I'd say anyone who wants to take on that housekeeping task should be given a pat on the back and a TWP T-Shirt.

Comment: @WesleyLong I suggest taking an Agile approach.  Don't take on the entire site, just take things on post by post.  If a member of the community edits and clarifies one post per week, that is a great success.  If folks become passionate about it and boost up to one per day, that's also a success. If they stop doing it, it's still a success because they cleaned up a total number of X posts.  And... it does make me wonder if SE is going to do any contests that involve t-shirt giveaways... hmmm... no t-shirts have been handed out in a long time!

Comment: @jmort253 - I'd agree with you.  I was referring to a theoretical "someone" who took it upon themselves to work a lot on this area.  If we notice a lot of old posts being edited by a user to link/define acronyms, person should be thanked and recognized.  I wasn't saying we should make it an "assignment," but I can see how I wasn't clear.

Comment: @WesleyLong no one can edit everything, but if we as users each edit a few things here and there the site ends up a lot better and creates a great culture for making useful, clear, and helpful questions (wow, that sounds like buzzword bingo, but I guess I mean what I say...)

Comment: And building on that, getting more people involved just scales better, results in less burnout, and less frustration. In the end, more involvement in these areas by more people results in a more sustainable process.

Comment: Guys, I wasn't debating any of that.  I was only saying that if Llopis wanted to tackle that, he should be acknowledged.  Something is apparently lost in translation, here.

Answer (score 0):

Acronyms which are specific to a company, country, trade or industry should be glossed (= accompanied by a brief explanation like this one) or linked. I wouldn't like to get on the wrong side any of these [ADA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada#Politics_and_government)s, but we might have more sensible advice about disability discrimination than handling drug cartels.

That said, there is no need to be zealous about this: if you don't know the term but you know this rule, it probably needs glossing. If you do know the term and are unsure, someone who doesn't know might ask and you then have your answer on whether it needs glossing. One or two unclear acronyms are never going to be a reason for closing a question.

A comment should suffice to clarify unless the question/answer is especially long and the comment would appear far from the usage. If it's unclear what it refers to, just ask! Where an answer contains lots of acronyms, it's probably best to edit, as many comments would be confusing.